# MySql crosstab 3 tables, T1=rows, T2=columns, T3=values

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I have a need to display user-levels for all possible users(T1) in all possible Pages(T2) whereby the values are stored in another table (T3) like:

> UserID, Page, Level(R,E,W,A,O)
>   (Read,Edit,Write,Assistant,Owner)

But I just can't understand how to dynamically get the columns made and then refer to it as LAST(col1)
Any hint in the right direction will be appreciated.

I know how to get it done in a number of foreach loops in php but I believe it should be possible in MySql?..

Tables look like:

Table 1; Users

```
ID | Name
------------------
1  | James
------------------
2  | John
------------------
3  | Peter
------------------
```

Table 2; Pages

```
ID | PageName
------------------
1  | Home
------------------
2  | Members
------------------
3  | Courses
------------------
4  | Lybrary
------------------
5  | StrangePage
------------------
6  | Unused Page
------------------
```

Table 3; UserLevels

```
ID | User       | Page      | Lev
---------------------------------------
1  | James      | Home      | W
---------------------------------------
2  | James      | Members   | R
---------------------------------------
3  | James      | Lybrary   | O
---------------------------------------
4  | John       | Home      | R
---------------------------------------
5  | Peter      | Home      | O
---------------------------------------
6  | Peter      | Courses   | A
---------------------------------------
```

Expected out put would contain all users as rows, all pages as columns, all permissions (where available) as results:

```
User  | Home | Members | Courses | Lybrary | StrangePage | Unused Page
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
James | W    | R       |         |         |             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
John  | R    |         |         |         |             | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Peter | O    |         | A       |         |             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show us your table structures?

Comment: structures added, thanks for the hint

Comment: Expected output from the given test data may be useful to us?

Comment: expected outcome added, thanks for that hint too ;-)